# How to make a link_to that redirects and submits a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, link-to

I have a modal that will serve as a disclaimer in my app and I need the link at the bottom of the modal that says "agree & continue" to toggle a boolean and input the time that the boolean was toggled. I have created the button as a form with hidden links but I cant seem to see how to make it submit the form AND redirect to the path i specify. Here is my link_to code now.

```
<% if current_user.user_record.blank? %>
            <%= form_for :user do |f| %>
            <% f.hidden_field :disclosure_acceptance, :value => true %>
            <% f.hidden_field :disclosure_date, :value => Time.now %>
            <%= link_to("Agree & Continue", user_steps_path(current_user), class: "btn btn-primary") %>
            <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a `new` method in your user_records_controller or at whichever controller action the form is displayed at:

```
 def new
   @user_record = current_user.build_user_record
 end
```

Put this in your view:

```
  <% if current_user.user_record.blank? %>
                <%= form_for @user_record do |f| %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :disclosure_acceptance, :value => true %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :disclosure_date, :value => Time.now %>
                <%=f.submit "Agree & Continue",  class: "btn btn-primary") %>
                <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Make a create action for the `user_record` that looks like this:

```
  def create
    @user_record = current_user.build_user_record(permitted_params) 
     if @user_record.save
      redirect_to user_steps_path(current_user) 
    else
      render :new
  end
 end



 private
   def permitted_params
      params.require(:user_record).permit(:disclosure_acceptance , :disclosure_date) #etc
   end
```

**UPDATE**

If you directly want to jump to the 'create' action, you can make your configuration like this:
 Add a custom action to your routes:

```
  post 'rate/:article_id' => 'user_records#create' :as => :create_user_record
                            #or whichever controller/action you wish
```

You should update the route on your form:

```
= form_tag create_user_record_path, :method=>'post'  do
  #etc
```

In order to create a user_record from the controller, you need to change things a little bit:

```
  def create
       current_user.user_record.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :disclosure_acceptance => params[:disclosure_acceptance] , :disclosure_date => params[:disclosure_date])
    if current_user.user_record.save 
      #etc

 end
```

Comment: user_steps_path is the first step in a wicked wizard so it wont accept the post

Comment: i mean to say "user_steps_path is the first step in a wicked wizard, it is throwing me an error of no route matches post user/dashboard which is the path the modal is on"

Comment: Just one clarification: is user_record an associated model or an attribute of the user?

Comment: So thank you for this but I am not sure this will work. My modal is on a user specific dashboard. The user_record model is just a model I can check to see if the user has completed some steps.The actual attribute that I am changing in the form is part of the user model. So I dont know if I should add these actions to the dashboard controller. Does that make sense?

Comment: The user is not being built but updated with the 2 attributes

Comment: Updated. If you're just updating attributes of an associated model, you need to replace .create with .update in your controller